# CSS Contraction

Tags: html, css, tabs

Hy,i'm in a bit of a problem with a css panel and i sick a bit of help , my code works well but if the user has the browser decrease in size the panel goes under the text here is what i mean :

This is how it looks in normal browser size :

[image]

This is how it looks if the user has the browser reduced in size :

[image]

It will be nice at least the text to be overlapped by the css panel, my wish was it to go in a new line but it is not working...

Hero is the HTML :

```
<div class"center"
    <div class="story">
 <div class="full-story">
  <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" padding="0" border="0">
   <tbody><tr>
    <td>
      </td>
   </tr>
   </tbody></table>
     </div>
     <div class="fullstory">
     <div class="imbd"><img src="{THEME}/dleimages/game.png"/></div><span class="imbdrate">[xfvalue_gamescore]</span>
    <div class="fullstory-posterfull">
            <div>[full-link]<img src="{image-1}" alt="{title}" />[/full-link]</div>
    </div>
    <div class="pos">
    <div id="content" class="post_single" role="main">



                            <div class="post_reviews theme_regular">
                                <ul role="tablist" class="tabs theme_field"><li  tabindex="0"  class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top ui-tabs-active ui-state-active"><a  href="http://[xfvalue_gsite]" class="theme_button">[xfvalue_author]</a></li><li aria-selected="false"  aria-controls="reviews_users" tabindex="-1" role="tab"><a tabindex="-1" role="presentation" href="#reviews_users" class="theme_button ui-tabs-anchor">[xfvalue_release]</a></li></ul>
            <div class="reviews_data">

                <div class="criteria_row theme_field">
                    <input name="reviews_marks_author[]" value="4" type="hidden">
                    <span class="criteria_label theme_strong">OS</span>[xfvalue_os]
                </div>

                <div class="criteria_row theme_field">
                    <input name="reviews_marks_author[]" value="4" type="hidden">
                    <span class="criteria_label theme_strong">Game size</span>[xfvalue_size]
                </div>

                <div class="criteria_row theme_field">
                    <input name="reviews_marks_author[]" value="5" type="hidden">
                    <span class="criteria_label theme_strong">Video Card</span>[xfvalue_vcard]
                </div>

                <div class="criteria_row theme_field">
                    <input name="reviews_marks_author[]" value="4" type="hidden">
                    <span class="criteria_label theme_strong">Genre(s)</span>[xfvalue_genre]
                </div>

                <div class="criteria_row theme_field">
                    <input name="reviews_marks_author[]" value="5" type="hidden">
                    <span class="criteria_label theme_strong">Mode(s)</span>[xfvalue_mode]
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="reviews_summary blog_reviews">
                <div class="criteria_summary_text criteria_row theme_field"><p class="sammorryp">[xfvalue_minisum]
</div>
                <div class="criteria_summary criteria_row theme_field">
                    <span class="criteria_label theme_strong">[xfvalue_age]</span>=
                    <span class="stars_off">
                </span></span>
                    <span class="criteria_mark theme_accent_bg">[xfvalue_score]</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
<table class="tab">
    <tbody><tr>
    <td><div class="fullstory-content"></div></td>
    </tr>
            <tr>
            <div class="flo">
    <td><div class="fullstory-title"><span class="moviedesctit">Game description:</span></div></td>
    </tr>
            <tr>
    <td><div class="movdiv"><span class="moviedesc">[xfvalue_gamedesc]</span></div>
    </div>
            </td>
   </tr>
   </div>
   </tbody></table>
   <br>
```

Here is the CSS :

```
.fullstory {overflow:hidden;}
.fullstory-title {color:#182131; font-size:14px; padding:0px 0 10px 10px; text-transform:uppercase;}
.fullstory-posterfull {border-collapse: separate;border-spacing: 0px;float:left; overflow:hidden; max-height:600px; border:1px solid #ccc;}
.fullstory-posterfull img {max-height:600px; max-width:600px; width:350px;z-index: 1;}
.fullstory-posterfull-info {margin:15px 0 0 10px; line-height:22px; float: right;}
.fullstory-info {float:left; margin:0 0 15px 25px; width:500px;}
.fullstory-info h1 {padding:0 0 5px 9px; font-size:20px; color:#FD821F; letter-spacing:-0.04em; text-transform:uppercase; font-weight:normal;}
.fullstory-info-fields {margin-bottom:5px;}
.fullstory-info-fields > div {border-bottom:1px solid #ddd; color:#2C2C2C; font-weight:bold; padding:5px 6px 5px 11px; position:relative; width:315px;}
.fullstory-info-fields > div > div {display:block; float:left; width:60px;}
.fullstory-info-fields > div > span {display:inline-block; font-weight:normal; margin-left:20px; width:130px;}
.fullstory-banner {width:20px; padding:10px; margin:5px 0 0 0; position:relative;}
.fullstory-service {overflow:hidden; margin:15px 0 15px 0;}
.imgstyle{border:1px solid #38576B;}
.center {
float:center;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 90%;
    background-color: #b0e0e6;
}

.imbd{
display:block;
position:absolute;
top: 420px; 
left: 350px;
overflow:hidden;
z-index: 10;
}

.imbdrate{
font-size:large;
font-weight:bold;
text-indent:1px;
color:#0067d9;
display:block;
position:absolute;
top: 424px;
left: 390px;
overflow:hidden;
z-index: 10;
}

.movdiv{
width: 500px;
 margin-bottom:-300px;
}

.moviedesc:first-letter{
               text-transform: uppercase;
          }
        .moviedesc {
        position: relative; 
        top: -290px;
        white-space: pre-wrap;
        color: #424242;
        font-family: "Adobe Caslon Pro", "Hoefler Text", Georgia, Garamond, Times, serif;
    letter-spacing:0.1em;
    text-align:center;
    margin:50px auto;
    text-transform: lowercase;
    line-height: 135%;
    font-size: 11pt;
    font-variant: small-caps;
        }

        .moviedesctit:first-letter{
               text-transform: uppercase;
          }
        .moviedesctit {
        position: relative; 
        top: -300px;
        white-space: pre-wrap;
        font-weight:bold;
        color: #424242;
        font-family: "Adobe Caslon Pro", "Hoefler Text", Georgia, Garamond, Times, serif;
    letter-spacing:0.1em;
    text-align:center;
    margin:50px auto;
    text-transform: lowercase;
    line-height: 145%;
    font-size: 12pt;
    font-variant: small-caps;
        }



.sammorryp{
padding: 5px 0 5px 0;
width:270px; 
 line-height: 13px; 
 text-indent: 13px; 
 margin: 0;
 font-family: helvetica,sans-serif;
color: #9C9C9C;
font-size: 12px;
font-weight: bold;
font-style: italic;
text-align: center;
letter-spacing: 0.4pt;
word-spacing: 0.2pt;
line-height: 2.2;
}

/* Tabs */
.tabs,
.widget ul.tabs {
    position:relative;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
}
.tabs li,
.widget .tabs li {
    display:inline-block;
    margin:0 1px 0 0;
    padding:0;
}
.tabs li:before,
.widget .tabs li:before {
    display:none;
}
.tabs li a,
.widget .tabs li a {
    height:40px;
    line-height:40px;
    padding:0 10px;
    display:inline-block;
    text-align:center;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}


/* Page navigation*/
#nav_pages,
#nav_pages_parts {
    overflow: hidden;
    clear: both;
    margin-top: 1px;
    padding:30px 20px;
}
#nav_pages ul {
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#nav_pages li {
    margin-right: 5px;
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
}
#nav_pages li a,
#nav_pages li span,
.nav_pages_parts a,
.nav_pages_parts > span,
.nav_comments a,
.nav_comments > span {
    -webkit-transition: all ease .2s;
    -moz-transition: all ease .2s;
    -ms-transition: all ease .2s;
    -o-transition: all ease .2s;
    transition: all ease .2s;   
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align:center;
    display: inline-block;
    width:36px;
    height:36px;
    line-height:36px;
}
.nav_pages_parts {
    margin: 10px  0;
}
.nav_pages_parts > span.pages {
    text-align:left;
    width:auto;
}
#nav_pages .pager_pages span {  
    width:90px; 
    text-align:left;
}
#nav_pages .pager_first a,
#nav_pages .pager_last a {
    width:60px; 
}
.nav_pages_parts.nav_pages_attachment {
    text-align:center;
    margin:1px 0 0 0;
}
.nav_pages_parts.nav_pages_attachment > span {
    margin-right:1px;
}
.nav_pages_parts.nav_pages_attachment a,.nav_pages_parts.nav_pages_attachment > span {
    vertical-align:top;
    width:100px;
}


/* View more button */
#viewmore {
    clear:both;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding-top:20px;
    padding-bottom:20px;
    width: 310px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#viewmore.pagination_infinite {
    visibility:hidden;
    padding:0;
    height:0;
    position:relative;
}
#viewmore_link {
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    height:54px;
    line-height:54px;
    text-align:center;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}
#viewmore_link span {
    display:inline-block;
}
#viewmore_link .viewmore_loading {          display:none; margin-right:10px; }
#viewmore_link .viewmore_loading:before {   font-size: 16px; }
#viewmore_link.loading .viewmore_loading {  display:inline-block; }
#viewmore_link.loading .viewmore_text_1 {   display:none; }
#viewmore_link .viewmore_text_2 {           display:none; }
#viewmore_link.loading .viewmore_text_2 {   display:inline-block; }

#content article.viewmore {
    animation: zoomin .5s;
}


/* Tabs */
.theme_regular .ui-tabs-active .theme_button {
border-collapse: separate;
border-spacing: 0px;
    background:#00bcff;
    color:#ffffff;  
}
.theme_regular .sc_tabs .content {
    background: #fff;
    border-color: #e0e0e0;
}

/* Team */
.theme_regular .sc_team .sc_team_item {
    background: #f0f0f0;
}

/* Testimonials */
.theme_regular .sc_testimonials .sc_testimonials_position {
    color:#aaaaaa;
}
.theme_regular .sc_testimonials.sc_testimonials_style_flat .sc_testimonials_content {
    background:#f0f0f0;
}
.theme_regular .sc_testimonials.sc_testimonials_style_callout .sc_testimonials_content {
    background:#9b9b9b;
    color:#ffffff;
}
.theme_regular .sc_testimonials.sc_testimonials_style_callout .sc_testimonials_extra {
    background: #565656;
}
.theme_regular .sc_testimonials.sc_testimonials_style_callout .sc_testimonials_extra .sc_testimonials_extra_inner {
    border-color:transparent transparent #ffffff #ffffff;
}

/* Title */
.theme_regular .sc_title_bubble_top .sc_title_bubble_icon,
.theme_regular .sc_title_bubble_left .sc_title_bubble_icon {
    background-color:#00bcff;
    color:#ffffff;
}
.theme_regular .sc_title_underline:after {
    border-bottom-color:#00bcff;
}

/* Toggles */
.theme_regular .sc_toggles .sc_toggles_item .sc_toggles_title a span.sc_toggles_icon {
    background: #666666;
    color:#ffffff;
}
.theme_regular .sc_toggles .sc_toggles_item .sc_toggles_title.ui-state-active a span.sc_toggles_icon {
    background: #00bcff;
}
.theme_regular .sc_toggles .sc_toggles_item .sc_toggles_title.ui-state-active a {
    color:#00bcff;
}
.theme_regular .sc_toggles .sc_toggles_item .sc_toggles_title a:hover {
    color:#bbbbbb;
}
.theme_regular .sc_toggles .sc_toggles_item .sc_toggles_title a:hover span.sc_toggles_icon {
    background: #bbbbbb;
    color:#666666;
}


/* Form fields
---------------------------------------------------*/
.theme_regular #buddypress .button,
.theme_regular #buddypress .generic-button a,
.theme_regular #buddypress form input[type="button"],
.theme_regular #buddypress form input[type="reset"],
.theme_regular #buddypress form input[type="submit"],
.theme_regular.bbpress #bbpress-forums form input[type="button"],
.theme_regular.bbpress #bbpress-forums form input[type="submit"],
.theme_regular.bbpress #bbpress-forums form input[type="reset"],
.theme_regular button,
.theme_regular html input[type="button"],
.theme_regular input[type="reset"],
.theme_regular input[type="submit"] {
    border-color:transparent;
    border-width:0;
    background:#666666;
    color:#ffffff;  
    -webkit-transition: all ease .2s;
    -moz-transition: all ease .2s;
    -ms-transition: all ease .2s;
    -o-transition: all ease .2s;
    transition: all ease .2s;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.theme_regular #buddypress .button:hover,
.theme_regular #buddypress .generic-button a:hover,
.theme_regular #buddypress form input[type="button"]:hover,
.theme_regular #buddypress form input[type="reset"]:hover,
.theme_regular #buddypress form input[type="submit"]:hover,
.theme_regular.bbpress #bbpress-forums form input[type="button"]:hover,
.theme_regular.bbpress #bbpress-forums form input[type="submit"]:hover,
.theme_regular.bbpress #bbpress-forums form input[type="reset"]:hover,
.theme_regular button:hover,
.theme_regular html input[type="button"]:hover,
.theme_regular input[type="reset"]:hover,
.theme_regular input[type="submit"]:hover {
    background:#bbbbbb;
    color:#ffffff;  
}
.theme_regular #buddypress .button:focus,
.theme_regular #buddypress .generic-button a:focus,
.theme_regular #buddypress form input[type="button"]:focus,
.theme_regular #buddypress form input[type="reset"]:focus,
.theme_regular #buddypress form input[type="submit"]:focus,
.theme_regular.bbpress #bbpress-forums form input[type="button"]:focus,
.theme_regular.bbpress #bbpress-forums form input[type="submit"]:focus,
.theme_regular.bbpress #bbpress-forums form input[type="reset"]:focus,
.theme_regular button:focus,
.theme_regular html input[type="button"]:focus,
.theme_regular input[type="reset"]:focus,
.theme_regular input[type="submit"]:focus,
.theme_regular button:active,
.theme_regular html input[type="button"]:active,
.theme_regular input[type="reset"]:active,
.theme_regular input[type="submit"]:active {
    background:#bbbbbb;
    color:#ffffff;  
}
.theme_regular #buddypress form textarea,
.theme_regular #buddypress form#whats-new-form textarea,
.theme_regular #buddypress form select,
.theme_regular #buddypress form input[type="file"],
.theme_regular #buddypress form input[type="text"],
.theme_regular #buddypress form input[type="search"],
.theme_regular #buddypress form input[type="email"],
.theme_regular #buddypress form input[type="number"],
.theme_regular #buddypress form input[type="checkbox"],
.theme_regular #buddypress form input[type="radio"],
.theme_regular #buddypress form input[type="password"],
.theme_regular .theme_field,
.theme_regular blockquote,
.theme_regular input[type="text"],
.theme_regular input[type="number"],
.theme_regular input[type="email"],
.theme_regular input[type="password"],
.theme_regular input[type="search"],
.theme_regular select,
.theme_regular textarea {
    background: #dddddd;
    border-width:0;
    color: #666666;
}
.theme_regular #buddypress form textarea:focus,
.theme_regular #buddypress form#whats-new-form textarea:focus,
.theme_regular #buddypress form select:focus,
.theme_regular #buddypress form input[type="file"]:focus,
.theme_regular #buddypress form input[type="text"]:focus,
.theme_regular #buddypress form input[type="search"]:focus,
.theme_regular #buddypress form input[type="email"]:focus,
.theme_regular #buddypress form input[type="number"]:focus,
.theme_regular #buddypress form input[type="checkbox"]:focus,
.theme_regular #buddypress form input[type="radio"]:focus,
.theme_regular #buddypress form input[type="password"]:focus,
.theme_regular .theme_field:focus,
.theme_regular input[type="text"]:focus,
.theme_regular input[type="number"]:focus,
.theme_regular input[type="email"]:focus,
.theme_regular input[type="password"]:focus,
.theme_regular input[type="search"]:focus,
.theme_regular select:focus,
.theme_regular textarea:focus {
    background: #cccccc;
    color: #666666;
}

/* Color theme: 'Regular' */

/* Page Body background */
.theme_regular.theme_body, .theme_regular .theme_body {
    background:#f0f0f0;
}

/* Article background */
.theme_regular.theme_article, .theme_regular .theme_article {
    color:#666666;
    background:#ffffff;
}

/* Text color */
.theme_regular p, .theme_regular td, .theme_regular th, .theme_regular input, .theme_regular textarea, .theme_regular div,
.theme_regular .theme_text {
    color:#666666;
}

/* Headers color */
.theme_regular h1, .theme_regular h2, .theme_regular h3,
.theme_regular .theme_title, .theme_regular .theme_header {
    color:#222222;
}

/* SubHeaders color */
.theme_regular h4, .theme_regular h5, .theme_regular h6,
.theme_regular .theme_subtitle, .theme_regular .theme_subheader {
    color:#222222;
}

/* Strong text */
.theme_regular .theme_strong {
    color:#222222;
}

/* Info text - post date, author, comments etc. */
.theme_regular .theme_info {
    color:#aaaaaa;
}

/* Links (as text) */
.theme_regular a,
.theme_regular .theme_link {
    color:#00bcff;
}

/* Links (as text) hover */
.theme_regular a:hover,
.theme_regular .theme_link:hover {
    color:#bbbbbb;
}

/* Links (as button) */
.theme_regular a.more-link,
.theme_regular a.comment-reply-link,
.theme_regular .theme_button {
    background:#666666;
    color:#ffffff;  
    -webkit-transition: all ease .2s;
    -moz-transition: all ease .2s;
    -ms-transition: all ease .2s;
    -o-transition: all ease .2s;
    transition: all ease .2s;
}

/* Links (as button) hover */
.theme_regular a.more-link:hover,
.theme_regular a.comment-reply-link:hover,
.theme_regular a.theme_button:hover,
.theme_regular a.theme_accent_bg:hover,
.theme_regular .theme_hover {
    background:#bbbbbb;
    color:#ffffff;  
}

/* Border color */
.theme_regular fieldset,
.theme_regular .theme_border {
    border-color:#e0e0e0 !important;
}

/* Accent color */
.theme_regular .theme_accent_bg {
    background:#00a0db;
    color:#ffffff;
}
.theme_regular .theme_accent {
    color:#00a0db;
}
.theme_regular .theme_accent_border {
    border-color:#00a0db;
}

/* Reviews area */
.post_reviews {
border-collapse: separate;
border-spacing: 0px;
    width: 310px;
    float:right;
    position:relative;
    margin:24px -16px 10px 20px;
    overflow:hidden;
    font-size:14px;
    z-index:1;
}
.post_reviews .tabs {
    padding:15px 15px 0 15px;
}
.post_reviews #reviews_users {
    display:none;
}

.post_reviews .criteria_row {
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-bottom:1px;
    padding:12px 0 12px 12px;
    position:relative;
}
    .criteria_row .criteria_label {
        display:inline-block;
        width:150px;
        margin-right:10px;
        overflow:hidden;
    }
    .reviews_100 .criteria_row .criteria_label {
        width: 130px;
        margin-right:6px;
    }
    .blog_reviews .criteria_row .criteria_stars {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 120px;
        height: 28px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .reviews_10 .blog_reviews .criteria_row .criteria_stars {
        width:124px;
        height:20px;
    }
    .criteria_row .criteria_stars {
        display:inline-block;
        font-size:22px;
        white-space:nowrap;
        position:relative;
        vertical-align:top;
    }
    .reviews_users .criteria_row .criteria_stars {
        cursor:pointer;
    }
    .criteria_row .criteria_stars .theme_stars:before {
        content:'\e801';
        font-family:Fontello;
        -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
        display:inline-block;
        margin-right:5px;
    }
    .reviews_10 .criteria_row .criteria_stars .theme_stars:before {
        margin-right:0;
        font-size:14px;
        vertical-align:top;
    }
    .reviews_100 .criteria_row .criteria_stars {
        min-height:0;
        height:10px;
        width:86px;
        vertical-align:text-top;
        line-height:10px;
        font-size:10px;
    }
    .criteria_row .criteria_dragger {
        display:block;
        position:absolute;
        left:0;
        top:0;
        bottom:0;
        width:10px;
        background-color:#69F;
    }
    #reviews_author .criteria_row .criteria_dragger {
        display:none;
    }
    .criteria_row .criteria_bar {
        display:inline-block;
        width:80px;
        height:4px;
        margin-left:3px;
        margin-top:-2px;
        vertical-align:middle;
        text-align: left;
    }
    .criteria_row .criteria_level {
        display:inline-block;
        height:4px;
        width:0;
        vertical-align:top;
    }
    .criteria_row .criteria_mark, 
    .reviews_summary .criteria_summary .criteria_word {
        display:block;
        position:absolute;
        right:0;
        top:0;
        bottom:0;
        width:50px;
        text-align:center;
        font-weight:bold;
        font-size:18px;
        padding-top:12px;
        color:#ffffff;
    }
    .reviews_5 .criteria_row .criteria_mark,
    .reviews_10 .criteria_row .criteria_mark {
        display:none;
    }
    .reviews_100 .post_reviews .reviews_summary .criteria_summary > .theme_stars_on {
        display:none;
    }



/* Reviews Summary */
.reviews_summary.blog_reviews {
    overflow:hidden;
    margin:5px 0 0 0;
}
#content.post_single .reviews_summary.blog_reviews {
    margin:0px 0px 0 0;
    float:center;
}
.reviews_10 .reviews_summary .criteria_label {
    margin-right:6px;
}

.reviews_summary .criteria_summary {
    position:relative;
}
.reviews_summary .criteria_summary_text.criteria_row {
    height:auto;
    font-size:12px;
    line-height:16px;
    padding-top:12px;
    padding-bottom:12px;
}
.reviews_summary .criteria_label {
    text-transform:uppercase;
    display:inline-block;
    height:28px;
    line-height:32px;
}
.reviews_summary .criteria_stars {
    top:4px;
}
.reviews_10 .reviews_summary .criteria_stars {
    top:0;
}
.reviews_summary .criteria_stars .stars_on,
.reviews_summary .criteria_stars .stars_off {
    position:absolute;
    display:block;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    min-height:20px;
    line-height:20px;
    white-space:nowrap;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.reviews_summary .criteria_stars .stars_on {
    width:0;
}
.reviews_summary .criteria_stars .stars_off .theme_stars {  /* Override color themes settings */
    color: rgba(128,128,128,0.8);
}
.reviews_summary .criteria_summary .criteria_mark,
.reviews_summary .criteria_summary .criteria_word {
    width:150px;
    font-size:32px;
    line-height:32px;
}
.reviews_5 .reviews_summary .criteria_summary .criteria_mark,
.reviews_5 .reviews_summary .criteria_summary .criteria_word,
.reviews_10 .reviews_summary .criteria_summary .criteria_mark,
.reviews_10 .reviews_summary .criteria_summary .criteria_word {
    display:block;
    left:0;
    right:auto;
}
.reviews_5 .reviews_summary .criteria_summary .criteria_word,
.reviews_10 .reviews_summary .criteria_summary .criteria_word,
.reviews_summary .criteria_summary .criteria_word {
    display:none;
}
.reviews_author .reviews_summary .criteria_bar,
.reviews_users .reviews_summary .criteria_bar {
    display:none;
}
.reviews_summary .criteria_summary.show_word .criteria_word {
    display:block;
}
.reviews_summary .reviews_users_accept {
    display:none;
    padding:8px 10px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}
.reviews_users .criteria_summary_text.show_button {
    text-align:center;
    padding:15px 0;
}
.reviews_users .criteria_summary_text.show_button .criteria_summary_descr {
    display:none;
}
.reviews_users .criteria_summary_text.show_button .reviews_users_accept {
    display:inline-block;
}


/* Tabs */
.tabs,
.widget ul.tabs {
    position:relative;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
}
.tabs li,
.widget .tabs li {
    display:inline-block;
    margin:0 1px 0 0;
    padding:0;
}
.tabs li:before,
.widget .tabs li:before {
    display:none;
}
.tabs li a,
.widget .tabs li a {
    height:40px;
    line-height:40px;
    padding:0 10px;
    display:inline-block;
    text-align:center;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}
```

Comment: Look at using `%` instead of `px` for content widths in your css

Comment: Also look into responsive design

Comment: I well try with % , and responsive design i believe is ok because i have some other sections using similar code design and it is responsive...

Comment: Responsive design is a strategy... Just because a site looks ok with resizing doesn't mean its using responsive design, it is very possible its just dumb luck / browsers being smart

Comment: You can also look at media queries

Comment: If you care about responsive design, try using tables only for tabular data and not for layout. There are some techniques that get better results than tables, and media queries are not supported by IE8 and below, so there isn't much sense on using tables for layout.

Answer (score 0):

you can structure a CSS styling like this:

basically creating a container with your content can solve the problem
such that your content is dependent by the size and width of the container
by using % as width and height..

```
<html>

<style>
#container{
    border:solid blue;
    width:500px;
    height:500px;
    min-height:300px;
    min-width:300px;
}
#text_content{
    border:solid blue 1px;
    width:30%;
    float:left;
    height:60%;
    font-size:70%;


}
#side_nav{
    border:solid blue 1px;
    width:40%;
    height:90%;
    float:left;

}
</style>
<body>
<div id="container" >
<div id="text_content">
the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog near the riverbank
the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog near the riverbank
the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog near the riverbank
the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog near the riverbank
the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog near the riverbank

</div>
<div id="side_nav"></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

hope this can help

Comment: I may not use inline css by '<style>' because i'm using a CMS and the theme is not allowing that.... also Seth the theme is Bootstrap baseed so is 100% responsive design, im 99% sure is from my css i just don't know where i did the mistake...